# German gift tax threshold

Tags: germany, taxes

I'm close to purchasing a home in Germany and would like to receive a large sum of money in CAD from my parents.

Am I correct in saying that the first 400k is tax free, and everything after that is taxed at a certain rate? IE, I would only need to pay tax if the money **my parents give me** is greater than 400k.

Comment: this sounds correct, but for such amounts i would advice you hire a **tax consultant**. In case of any issues (like even if the amount is higher than 400k), there are options on how to deal with such situations (usually, **a notary** knows about options)